# Uncertainty principle in Z/pZ and number of zeros of sparse polynomial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, fourier-analysis

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308286), Terence Tao proves an uncertainty principle for cycle groups of prime order.

In summary, if you consider a function $f: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$ then $\operatorname{supp}(f)$, the support of $f$, is related to the support of its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ by the formula
$$\left|\operatorname{supp}(f)\right|+\left|\operatorname{supp}\left(\hat{f}\right)\right| \ge p+1 $$

In the abstract of the paper, it is written that a consequence of this is that a sparse polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of $k+1$ monomials can have at most $k$ zeroes.

I find this corollary very interesting; however I don't understand Tao's proof of it, which consists of proving that $P(z)=\sum_{i=1}^kc_iz^{n_i}$, when restricted to the $p$<sup>th</sup> roots of unity, can have at most $k$ zeroes among them.

Why does this imply that $P$ has at most $k$ roots in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: I think you misread what Terence Tao says, by forgetting to read the whole of the sentence. He does not say "a sparse polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of $k+1$ monomials can have at most $k$ zeroes" but rather that "a sparse polynomial $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of $k+1$ monomials, WHEN RESTRICTED TO THE $p$-TH ROOTS OF UNITY, can have at most $k$ zeroes" (on the middle of p.5, just after the end of the proof of Theorem 1.1)

Comment: This I understood :)
My question was about the claim in the abstract of the paper: "As one consequence, we see that a sparse polynomial in Z/pZ consisting of k+1 monomials can have at most k zeroes"

Comment: Well, the claim in the abstract is false. Consider $x^{p-1}-1$ over $\frac{\mathbb Z}{p\mathbb Z}$ ...

Comment: oh true ! thanks :)

Comment: I just suggested some small edits; nevertheless, I wanted to commend you as a new user on composing this post so well $\ddot\smile$ it was a very intriguing and comprehensible read!